# Daily averages in local time from UTC

Tags: convert, netcdf, time, climate, climate-data-operators

It has been almost 2 weeks since I started getting familiar with netCDF files and operators (NCO) and climate data operators (cdo) and I am not an experienced programmer.

I have a folder which contains (monthly) nc files from January 1980 to December 2015 (in total 432 nc files). Each of these nc files contains **hourly data** of different compounds (such as PM2.5, O3, NO2, NO, etc) for one month **in UTC** and I need to have netCDF files which will contain **daily averages in local time**.

A colleague of mine gave me the following instructions: first I need to identify the zone (let's name it z0) with [long1,long2], then identify the time (UTC--> local time, where UTC= 0h and LT=+1 and so on) and simultaneously derive the daily averages. He also told me that the final result e.g for one month should be an nc file with daily averages where 1 day should contain the averaged data of the different compounds where z0= UTC[0:23], z1= UTC[1:24]....etc....(This doesn't make any sense to me).

As I am quite new at this, it is very difficult for me to understand what and how I need to do it.

Since the time is in this format:

```
int time(time) ;
                time:units = "seconds since 1979-12-02 00:00:00 UTC" ;
                time:long_name = "time" ;
                time:axis = "T" ;
                time:calendar = "standard" ;
                time:standard_name = "time" ;
```

I thought the change from UTC to local time could be done with the command *ncatted*, and then I could move on with the code in order to get the daily averages. Any hints?

Comment: Do your netcdf files contain only data for 1 spatial location (i.e. one pair of lat-long), or is your data spatial? In other words, which dimensions are defined in the netcdf files, only "time" or also something like "longitude" and "latitude"?

Comment: The data are from different parts in the world. The dimensions are time, longitude and latitude and my variables are for example: time(time), lon(lon),lat(lat), PM2.5 (time, lon, lat), PM10 (time, lon, lat), O3 (time, lon, lat) and so on..